# Add recording timing for Android camera app afrter start button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I am new to android, I want to add recording timing for my camera app when start button is pressed,any suggestion please

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I am trying to create live broadcasting app for android,For that i want to implement total streaming time(like stop watch time),how to implement it over camera preview activity

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding Chronometer to you application.

- Add `Chronometer.start()`method while start button is Pushed.
- And add`Chronometer.stop()`when stop button is pushed

Note: add `Chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())`Before the `Chronometer.start()`to start the Chronometer from o,

Comment: yes your right i already using Chronometer for my application and it is working fine,Thank you for your replay

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like below at time when you start recording ,

```
Timer timerRecordVideo = new Timer();
        timerRecordVideo .schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        txtVideoCountdonw.setText(getTimeInMinute(countDonw));
                        countDonw++;
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 00, 1000);

    private String getTimeInMinute(int secs)
    {
        // int minute = ;
        // int sec = secs % 60;

        String min = String.valueOf(secs / 60);
        String sec = String.valueOf(secs % 60);

        if (sec.length() == 1)
            sec = "0" + sec;

        if (min.length() == 1)
            min = "0" + min;

        return min + ":" + sec;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What i get from your question is you want to get the recording time. if it is that then you can do it in this way when start button you can get current time by calling.

```
Date dateStart = new Date();
long timeStart = dateStrat.getTime();
```

and when user finishes recording call

```
 Date dateEnd = new Date();
 long timeEnd = dateEnd.getTime();
```

and then you can get the total time just by subtractin timeStart from timeEnd.
now,

```
long totalTime = timeEnd-timeStart;
String t = String.format("%tT", totalTime-TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
```

in this way you can get a string representation of the time elapsed. Now, you can use it the way you want.

Comment: This is exactly what i want,if you can give some example.Thank you..

Comment: Thanks for your code,i will try this and get you back gaurav